# How to iterate through only files containing certain strings in for loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am trying to figure out how to use only the files containing certain strings in my for loop code, and I am having trouble thinking through the order of how this should be sorted out.

I have the following code:

```
folder = 'Path/to/My/Folder'

for f in folder:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df_new = df['Value'] * 2
    df_new.to_csv('Path/to/My/Folder/Name.csv')
```

What this does is go to my folder and FOR EACH file in my folder, all .csv files, open the .csv file as a dataframe, and multiply the 'Value' column by 2, and then send that new dataframe to an output .csv file. However, what I want to do, is only iterate the files in the folder that contain certain strings, so for this example, only using the file if the string contains 'Blue', 'Red' or 'Green'. I would then want to append those color names as strings to the ouput .csv files so I know which is which. This is what I am thinking:

```
l = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']

folder = 'Path/to/My/Folder'

for f in folder IF contains l:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df_new = df['Value'] * 2
    df_new.to_csv(f'Path/to/My/Folder/Name_{i}.csv')
```

So now I made a list of the strings of interest. So my code now is saying loop through the files in the folder to do the operation, but ONLY use those files that contain either 'Blue', 'Red', or 'Green' in the file name. And then lastly, append the color name to the output .csv file name, so I know which output file is which. Is this the correct approach? I am confused about how to actually structure this logically with the correct syntax.

Comment: I'm still unclear: are you saying that you only want to deal with, say, "Blue" if the _filename_ contains the string `Blue`? Or if, anywhere in the file, the string `Blue` occurs?

Comment: Ah I see, I should have been more clear there. I meant to say that I only want to use files that contain, any where in the file name string 'Blue', 'Red', or 'Green'. So the 'folder' is like a pool of files that I can run through my for loop code. 'Blue_data.csv', 'Red_data.csv', and 'Green_data.csv' will all be used, but if there is a 'Purple_data.csv' in 'folder' it will be ignored and not used.

Comment: When you need file path to match some pattern, you should use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Comment: What would you want to happen for a file named `RedBlueGreen.csv`?

Comment: Oh wow, had not thought about that, but no, as I would want it ideally, the code would reject `RedBlueGreen.csv`. However, given that pragmatically I would not have that file, then yes, it would hypothetically include it. In other words. Yes, the code would accept `RedBlueGreen.csv` and I would just deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for this purpose. There, you can specify patterns that your file names should match up.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not an issue, than this code should work for you:

```
colors = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']
folder = 'Path/to/My/Folder'

for f in folder:
    for color in colors:
        if color in f:
            df = pd.read_csv(f)
            df['Value'] = df['Value'] * 2
            df.to_csv(f'Path/to/My/Folder/Name_{color}.csv')
```

If you see any warning, use pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

Comment: Thanks for this helpful suggestion. Though just so I understand, for the line `for color in colors:`, does this mean any file in folder that is directly called `Blue`, `Red`, or `Green`, or just any file in the folder that contains these colors somewhere in the file name string? The second circumstance there is what I am trying to going for. Also, would there be a way to account for all files that not only contain the colors, but that are also `.tif` files?

Comment: It checks whether the color is present as a substring ( anywhere in the file_name). If you also want .tif files then you can use another if condition just before the second for loop:               `if '.tif' in file_name:`
So, using this the program will first check if the file contains '.tif' then it checks whether the color is present anywhere in the file_name.
Hope that answers your questyion